# How to use environment variables in ReactJS imported CSS?

Tags: css, reactjs, environment-variables, create-react-app

I created a simple React app using https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app.

I am trying to specify a configurable URL to a component's CSS like this:

```
.Cell {
    background-image: url({process.env.REACT_APP_STATIC_URL}./someImage.png);
}
```

And here's the component:

```
import React from 'react';
import './Cell.css'

class Cell extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div className="Cell">
                {this.props.name}
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

But it doesn't look like the process variable trickles down to the imported CSS. How would I go about doing this?

Comment: Do you have a reply for this? I am facing the same question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to use js variables in CSS, try React inline-style instead of plain css file.

https://facebook.github.io/react/tips/inline-styles.html

If you want to separate CSS and JS, you might need a CSS preprocessor to manage your global variables.

Comment: But, I have a scenario where the background image will be set or unset based on media queries which is defined in .scss. In such a case, I cannot have inline style

Answer (score -2):

I came across one such scenario, The method I used is instead of adding it as background in CSS, make an img element and assign the path as src in component itself. I don't think there is any other way of doing that.

Answer (score -2):

Commenting on this as I've recently had a similar issue.  This should work to send an image file as a CSS variable in a build.

- use the style prop to invoke a CSS style
- Use template literal around the url() value
- use the Javascript require() to refer to the file in the final build pack.  Using a relative url requires that you call the image relative to where the the  page will be called instead of being relative to the component JS file.

In the React component, use the inline style prop to set the CSS variable:

```
<div 
style={{"--img":`url( ${require("../../images/coding.jpg")})`}}>
</div>
```

in the CSS file:

```
background-image: var(--img);
```